# Read excel file from string using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read an excel file from a string using Apache POI 3.9 without any success. I am not too familiar with java.

Just to clarify, in my program I already have the excel file as a string and I am mocking that behaviour by using the readFile function.

Program:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class Test {

    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException 
    {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return encoding.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        String result = readFile("data.xlsx", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
    }

}
```

The error I am getting is:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:193)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:127)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:55)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:83)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:267)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:73)
    at Test.main(Test.java:28)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

cheers

Comment: You may find this library useful: https://github.com/eaorak/excelr

Answer (score 8):

So the fix for my problem was

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        byte[] result = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("data.xlsx"));     
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(result);
        Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? As explained in the [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), going via a stream [uses more memory than using the file directly](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

Comment: The reason I am doing this is that I am getting this file in a web service.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're making this way too complicated.  Just follow the [Apache POI Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html), which suggests reading the file with a `FileInputStream`.  There's no need for reading the bytes into a byte array and using a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Use one of the following, copied from the guide:

```
// Use a file
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("MyExcel.xls"));

// Use an InputStream, needs more memory
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("MyExcel.xlsx"));
```

Comment: I have added a clarification to my question.

Comment: It is unclear why you think you need to convert the contents of the file to a `String` before you create a `Workbook`.  You don't need to do so.

Comment: I agree. But in my program, I wanted to build a abstraction over some of my code. I think String would have the wrong thing and and an InputStream is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing? You're reading a binary file into a `byte[]` and convert it to a `String` using UTF-8. Later you're converting it back to a byte stream using UTF-8 again. What for? Skip all the steps inbetween:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("data.xlsx");
    Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This bugged me for a while.  None of the suggested fixes worked for me.  What did resolve the issue was to add a  to the maven-resources-plugin, thus

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                <nonFilteredFileExtension>docx</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                <nonFilteredFileExtension>xls</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                <nonFilteredFileExtension>xlsx</nonFilteredFileExtension>
              </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```